# No console key up event while shift key is pressed

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console

I have a piece of code that will read a key event from the console using the ReadConsoleInput function. It works mostly, except that it fails to read when a button is released while the shift key is pressed.

I wrote the most minimal example code I could. What it does right now is reads whether the 'a' key is pressed or not and displays it to the screen. If you run it and press 'a' you get

```
41[down]
41[up]
```

if you run it and hold down the shift key before pressing 'a', all you get is

```
41[down]
```

and you will not get a key up event until you release the shift key and press 'a' again.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Tchar.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE rhnd = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    while(1)
    {

        INPUT_RECORD buf[128];
        DWORD Events = 0;
        DWORD EventsRead = 0;

        GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(rhnd, &Events);
        if(Events == 0)continue;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<sizeof(buf);++i)//clear buf in case ReadConsoleInput doesn't do it for me, probably unnecessary
            ((char *)buf)[i]=0;
        ReadConsoleInput(rhnd, buf, 128, &(EventsRead));
        for(i=0;i<128;++i)//I would just loop while i<EventsRead but this ensures there are not extra elements (a little paranoid, I know)
        {
            if(buf[i].EventType == KEY_EVENT && (buf[i].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode & 0xff) == 0x41 /*keycode for 'a' button -- you can remove this condition to see the results for all key presses*/)
            {
                printf("%x",buf[i].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode);
                if(buf[i].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
                {
                    printf("[down]\n");
                }
                else //if this else gets executed it's what I'm calling a key up event
                    //this conditional should only be reached if either 'a' is pressed or 'a' was just released
                   //and the else should only be executed if it was just released
                {
                    printf("[up]\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it

Compiled on windows 10 using gcc (MinGW-64) and also using Visual Studio 15

Comment: The documentation for `INPUT_RECORD` is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683499(v=vs.85).aspx which shows that if it's not of type KEY_EVENT I should be ignoring it for this purpose (the KeyEvent member would not even exist to grab values from). The other condition I have run without and it shows only the shift key going [down] and [up] in addition to the 'a' key.

Comment: Cannot reproduce using VC10. Getting the up-event independently of the shift-keys' state(s).

Comment: Interesting. I am using gcc (MinGW-w64) to get this issue

Comment: ... compiled and tested on Win7.

Comment: Windows 10, I've edited to say both those things

Comment: I've just tested my code on visual studio 15 and achieved the same result as before (failure to see key up when shift key pressed)